# Java Thread NullPointerException with ServerSockets

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, serversocket

I'm trying to get this code to run 5 separate SocketServers on separate ports.  I'm getting NullPointerExceptions from the threads but I don't understand why.  Some help would be great.

line 72 is the server's accept method:

> Socket socket = server.accept();

```
public class TCPSocketServer {

    /**
    * Accept this many connections.
    */
    private int my_backlog = 5;

    /**
    * The server socket.
    */
    private ServerSocket server = null;

    private static final int SERVICE_DISCOVERY_PORT = 1234;
    private static final int ADDITION_SERVICE_PORT = 1235;
    private static final int DIVISION_SERVICE_PORT = 1236;
    private static final int MULTIPLICATION_SERVICE_PORT = 1237;
    private static final int SUBTRACTION_SERVICE_PORT = 1238;

    final static int[] SERVICE_PORTS = {   
                                SERVICE_DISCOVERY_PORT,
                                ADDITION_SERVICE_PORT,
                                DIVISION_SERVICE_PORT,
                                MULTIPLICATION_SERVICE_PORT,
                                SUBTRACTION_SERVICE_PORT
                            };

    /**
    * Create the server socket.
    * @param a_port the port that the server socket should listen on.
    */
    public TCPSocketServer(int port) {

        ServerSocket server = null;

            try {
                server = new ServerSocket(port, my_backlog);

                System.out.println("Service discovery listening on port " + port);

            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }
    } // end TCPSocketServer method


    public void listen() {

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {            
                    try {
                        Socket socket = server.accept();

                        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                        double dividend = in.readDouble();
                        double divisor = in.readDouble();

                        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                        double result = 0;
                        result = dividend/divisor; // TODO: check for zero divisor
                        out.writeDouble(result); // TODO: separate into divide() method
                        out.flush();

                        // tidy up
                        in.close();
                        out.close();
                        socket.close();

                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        ioe.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (SecurityException se) {
                        se.printStackTrace();
                    } // end try/catch
                } // end while loop
            } // end run()
        }.start(); // end Thread
    } // end listen()




// the main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int port = 0;

            for(int servicePort : SERVICE_PORTS){
                // Create the server
                TCPSocketServer socketServer = new TCPSocketServer(servicePort);
                // Listen on the server socket. This will run until the program is
                // killed.
                socketServer.listen();
            }

    } // end main
}
```

Here's some sample output:

```
Service discovery listening on port 1234
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at TCPSocketServer$1.run(TCPSocketServer.java:72)
Service discovery listening on port 1235
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at TCPSocketServer$1.run(TCPSocketServer.java:72)
Service discovery listening on port 1236
Exception in thread "Thread-2" Service discovery listening on port 1237java.lang.NullPointerException
    at TCPSocketServer$1.run(TCPSocketServer.java:72)

Exception in thread "Thread-3" Service discovery listening on port 1238
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at TCPSocketServer$1.run(TCPSocketServer.java:72)
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at TCPSocketServer$1.run(TCPSocketServer.java:72)
```

Comment: Please identify line **72** in your server code.

Comment: I pasted this into an editor and by my reckoning, L72 is the `ioe.printStackTrace()` in the anonymous `Thread` object, which can't be null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ServerSocket server = null` in your `TCPSocketServer(int port)` constructor is shadowing the `ServerSocket server` member higher up.  Take the one out of your constructor and you should be good to go.

Comment: And then fix the duplicate closing issue with the data streams. It will throw exception right after this one gets fixed :).

Comment: You know, it's been a long time since I wrote sockets in Java, but I recall actually doing the `accept` in one thread, then spawning new threads to handle the returned `Socket`s.  I suspect this implementation will actually be single-threaded, which is perhaps not what the author wanted (but not what they asked ;) *Edit* I take it back - it looks like one thread per `SERVICE_PORT` :)